# Why do we need node.js to be installed on system before running Mobile automation scripts through appium

Tags: node.js, appium

I am not sue... we need node.js to be installed if we want to run appium server through command prompt.

This is what i found on appium site
If you want to run Appium via an npm install, hack with or contribute to Appium, you will need node.js and npm 4 or greater (use n or brew install node to install Node.js. Make sure you have not installed Node or Appium with sudo, otherwise you’ll run into problems). We recommend the latest stable version.

But still not able to understand whether we need node.js to be used compulsory in appium, if yes...then why ?

Answer (score 3):

If Appium tools are written in Node then you Need node to run it.

If they were written in Python then you would need Python. If they were written in Java then you would need Java. You need a correct runtime to run every software unless it is compiled into machine code and saved as a native binary for the given architecture, which is not the case with JavaScript/Node (or Python, Java, Perl, Ruby, etc.).

When you go to the Appium's source code, you will see that it needs Node and which version it needs, in the package.json file:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4",
    "npm": ">=3"
  },
```

See the file at:

- https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/package.json#L25

Comment: Actually you need Node to run Javascript locally... Main.js or Appium.js in before versions. Anyway everything else is perfectly explained

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with above comment Appium is a server written in Node.js also you need Node for [Paralleization](https://github.com/isonic1/appium-workshop/blob/master/Appium%20Windows%20Installation%20Instructions.md#install-node-we-need-this-for-paralleization)